# Como descobrir se eu preciso girar a imagem

Tags: c#, imagem, ocr

estou implementando algumas funcionalidades para realizar OCR em imagens e até momento tudo está indo muito bem. 
O problema é; o OCR funciona bem se a imagem estiver na rotação correta, caso ela esteja de cabeça para baixa ou em rotação de 90° o OCR acaba pegando textos que eu chamaria de lixo, pois não fariam sentido no momento de trabalhar com eles.

Imaginem está imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que ela está de cabeça para baixo. Fazer a rotação dela é tranquilo, mas como checar se ela está de cabeça para baixo, para poder rotacioná-la?

Comment: Esses documentos possuem algum padrão?

Comment: @JoãoPauloMassa não possuem padrão, o OCR faz a leitura em qualquer imagem

Comment: demora muito o processo ? e se lesse... se tiver lixo, roda, lê de novo... até encontrar o correto. Não entendo de OCR, apenas uma sugestão

Comment: A leitura não demora, ele lê o texto mesmo estando virado... Mas ai o texto vem algo como SOMAV (ao invés de VAMOS)... @RovannLinhalis também pensei em ficar lendo o texto até ter um acerto maior, mas ai o processamento leva mais tempo e imagine que posso ler mais de 1000 imagens a cada 10 minutos...

Comment: Os documentos são gerados por você? Você pode tentar ler algum trecho do documento e ver se ele é algo "válido" como uma data.

Comment: @CypherPotato as imagens vem de usuários comuns... Para que eu possa checar precisaria de um padrão, mas não tenho nenhum padrão de imagem que possa ser enviado para ser lido... Podem haver documentos tipo (folha de pagamento, leis, formulários, relatórios etc).

Comment: Acontece algum erro ao ler estes documentos se estiverem virados ao contrário? Se sim, você pode implementar um `try...catch` até funcionar corretamente, mas se não for a questão, terá que implementar uma inteligência artificial para entender se as imagens estão viradas ou não.

Comment: Não ocorre erro... Ele lê sem dó o arquivo. Encontrei algumas coisas sobre trocar a tonalidade da imagem e por ai vai no SO em inglês, mas imaginei que a solução para checar a imagem pudesse ser mais simples.

Comment: Se souber um pouco de inglês, dá uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559525/how-to-detect-image-orientation-text).

Comment: Qual ferramenta OCR você está usando? Vê se esse post te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809499/android-java-detect-text-orientation-and-rotate-image-for-ocr. Pelo que é dito alguns frameworks OCR já possuem essa funcionalidade.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMassa Estou utilizando o Microsoft Vision. Estava utilizando a solução da ABBYY, porém a da MS é mais eficiente na questão da leitura, mas não encontrei nada que pudesse girar automaticamente a imagem.

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo, conseguiu resolver o problema? Qual API você está usando?

Comment: Olá @JoãoPauloMassa estou utilizando a Microsoft Vision e ela faz a leitura de imagens em até 30° de rotacionamento. Não resolvi a questão de detectar e virar automaticamente a imagem (180°) ainda.

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo, Eu fiz um teste com a Computer Vision API. É essa que você está utilizando?

Comment: Esta mesmo @JoãoPauloMassa.

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo. Você pode setar parâmetros na requisição onde um deles é o detectOrientation=true. A própria API identifica a posição da imagem e faz as modificações necessárias para capturar as informações. Se você não usou essa propriedade como parâmetro, posso criar uma resposta exemplificando.

Comment: Agradeço @JoãoPauloMassa porém a api deles rotaciona apenas 30° (ângulo pra correção da imagem). Conforme a documentação deles informa: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/home#RecognizeText

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tecnologias OCR mais recentes possuem configurações de rotação automática. A `Computer Vision API` contém essa configuração por meio da propriedade `detectOrientation`. De acordo com os testes que fiz essa propriedade por default é true, ou seja, ao realizar a verificação da imagem a API já rotaciona a imagem para capturar as informações.

Atribuindo parametros a requisição:

```
var requestParameters = "language=pt&detectOrientation=true";
```

Utilizando a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado com o `detectOrientation` igual a true

```
{
    "language": "pt",
    "textAngle": 0.0,
    "orientation": "Down",
    "regions": [{
        "boundingBox": "5,14,503,202",
        "lines": [{
            "boundingBox": "9,14,498,40",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "9,14,27,32",
                "text": "If"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "46,22,59,32",
                "text": "you"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "118,22,59,23",
                "text": "can"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "191,15,73,31",
                "text": "read"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "276,15,59,31",
                "text": "this"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "348,15,70,31",
                "text": "with"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "431,22,76,31",
                "text": "easy"
            }]
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "5,70,503,37",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "5,77,59,30",
                "text": "you"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "79,77,52,24",
                "text": "are"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "143,70,131,31",
                "text": "twisted!"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "296,70,67,32",
                "text": "And"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "378,70,79,32",
                "text": "have"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "470,77,38,24",
                "text": "an"
            }]
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "10,124,493,34",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "10,132,156,26",
                "text": "awesome"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "179,125,105,33",
                "text": "talent!"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "310,124,71,32",
                "text": "This"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "391,126,27,30",
                "text": "is"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "432,125,71,31",
                "text": "both"
            }]
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "15,175,485,41",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "15,175,175,34",
                "text": "backwards"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "204,178,59,32",
                "text": "and"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "278,179,108,37",
                "text": "upside"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "399,179,101,30",
                "text": "down!"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Agora o mesmo teste setando o valor da propriedade para `false`

```
var requestParameters = "language=pt&detectOrientation=false";
```

Resultado com o `detectOrientation` igual a `false`

```
{
    "language": "pt",
    "textAngle": 0.0,
    "orientation": "NotDetected",
    "regions": [{
        "boundingBox": "4,15,503,202",
        "lines": [{
            "boundingBox": "12,15,485,41",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "12,22,101,30",
                "text": "-iUMOP"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "126,15,108,37",
                "text": "ap!Sdn"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "249,21,59,32",
                "text": "pue"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "322,22,175,34",
                "text": "sp]ewpeq"
            }]
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "9,73,493,33",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "9,75,71,31",
                "text": "l.poq"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "94,75,27,30",
                "text": "s!"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "346,73,156,26",
                "text": "awosame"
            }]
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "4,124,503,37",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "4,130,38,24",
                "text": "ue"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "149,129,67,32",
                "text": "puv"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "238,130,131,31",
                "text": "ipaF!Ma"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "381,130,52,24",
                "text": "ae"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "448,124,59,30",
                "text": "noÁ"
            }]
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "5,177,498,40",
            "words": [{
                "boundingBox": "5,178,76,31",
                "text": "Ásea"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "94,185,70,31",
                "text": "qa!M"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "248,185,73,31",
                "text": "pea]"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "335,186,59,23",
                "text": "ueo"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "407,177,59,32",
                "text": "noÁ"
            }, {
                "boundingBox": "476,185,27,32",
                "text": "JI"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

[Aqui](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc) você pode visualizar as propriedades e realizar testes utilizando a `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`.

Utilizei para o meu teste o exemplo disponibilizado [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp).

Realizei também o teste com a sua imagem, na minha opinião funcionou como esperado, porém a distribuição dos textos não ajudam. (Não coloquei o Json todo porque passou do limite de caracteres de uma resposta)

```
{
"language": "pt",
"textAngle": 0.0,
"orientation": "Down",
"regions": [{
    "boundingBox": "1113,32,57,20",
    "lines": [{
        "boundingBox": "1113,32,57,20",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "1113,32,57,20",
            "text": "-Dep-"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "boundingBox": "198,59,228,18",
    "lines": [{
        "boundingBox": "198,59,228,18",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "198,61,47,16",
            "text": "Nome"
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "257,60,24,17",
            "text": "do"
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "296,59,130,18",
            "text": "Funcionario"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "boundingBox": "572,58,129,22",
    "lines": [{
        "boundingBox": "572,58,129,22",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "572,58,129,22",
            "text": "Cargo-Nivel"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "boundingBox": "777,33,319,94",
    "lines": [{
        "boundingBox": "1017,33,58,20",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "1017,33,58,20",
            "text": "Carga"
        }]
    }, {
        "boundingBox": "1005,57,82,17",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "1005,57,82,17",
            "text": "Horaria"
        }]
    }, {
        "boundingBox": "777,107,319,20",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "777,108,34,17",
            "text": "054"
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "825,107,190,18",
            "text": "GLES-L.4.620-FMS"
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "1030,107,66,20",
            "text": "111,11"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "boundingBox": "1363,29,106,47",
    "lines": [{
        "boundingBox": "1364,29,105,18",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "1364,29,57,18",
            "text": "Total"
        }, {
            "boundingBox": "1435,29,34,17",
            "text": "das"
        }]
    }, {
        "boundingBox": "1363,56,106,20",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "1363,56,106,20",
            "text": "Vantagens"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "boundingBox": "66,60,1430,1191",
    "lines": [{
        "boundingBox": "66,60,106,18",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "66,60,106,18",
            "text": "Matricula"
        }]
    }, {
        "boundingBox": "1401,180,70,21",
        "words": [{
            "boundingBox": "1401,180,70,21",
            "text": "302,36"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Estou nesta linha também, por enquanto vem dando certo (mesmo a documentação indicando apenas 30°) ela esta lendo bem o que está sendo preciso. Obrigado pela contribuição, foi de grande ajuda nossa discussão!

Comment: @ThiagoAraújo, Tmj :D

Answer (score 1):

Se a imagem conter o padrão EXIF você consegue identificar e rotacionar se necessário.

> O EXIF (Exchangeable Image File Format) é um padrão especificado e
>   seguido pelos fabricantes de câmaras digitais que gravam informações
>   sobre as características técnicas da captura de determinada imagem em
>   formato JPG ou TIFF.

Pegando uma imagem que contem o EXIF atraves de uma URL:

```
WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData("https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples/blob/master/Portrait_3.jpg?raw=true");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Pegando a orietanção e rotacionando:

```
int idOrientacao = 0x0112; // id da propridade que contem a orientação, 247 hex.
if (img.PropertyIdList.Contains(idOrientacao)) { // verificando se a imagem possui a propridade que contem a informação da orientação, imagens sem EXIF não possuem.
    int valorOrientacao =  (int) img.GetPropertyItem(idOrientacao).Value[0]; // valor que representa a orientação da imagem, tabela explicava logo abaixo.
    switch (valorOrientacao) {
            case 1:
                // Não precisa rotacionar
                break;
            case 2:
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
                break;
            case 3:
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                break;
            case 4:
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                break;
            case 5:
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
                break;
            case 6:
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                break;
            case 7:
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
                break;
            case 8:
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                break;
        }
    // Aqui você remove a propridade que contem a orientação, já que ela foi alterada.
    img.RemovePropertyItem(idOrientacao);
}
```

Valores possíveis para a variavel `valorOrientação`: documentação [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa916453.aspx#Anchor_130).

Opções de rotação: documentação [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/subscriptions/system.drawing.rotatefliptype(v=vs.100)).

Comment: As imagens que faço a leitura são .png ou .jpg, se eu converter elas para EXIF elas vão passar a ter estas propriedades?

Comment: Vai ter a propriedade, mas na conversão não é identificado o tipo de rotação, vai vir como se não estivesse rotacionado.